# Renewal ratio window function method

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query such as

```
select count(case when t.cnt > 1 then 1 end)/count(t.*)
from
(select signup_id, count(date_transaction) as cnt
from transactions
group by signup_id) t
```

This gives me renewal ration based on if a signup_id has more than 1 date_transaction value or row

I am trying to do the same utilizing a window function below and was trying to figure out if there is a better method then what I have below or if the below looks correct?

```
select count(CASE WHEN t.rnk > 1 THEN 1 END) / count(t.*) as renewal_ratio
from
(select *, row_number() over (partition by signup_id order by date_transaction asc) rnk
from table) t
```

Comment: The queries are not equivalent. The former gives one row per `signup_id` whereas the latter counts each row except the most first. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29f5633a22bea0ba636ac1aee29fec79 PS. `COUNT(t.*)` is incorrect, you must use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: thanks, why is t.* wrong to use?, how come I cannot alias the count(*) like I can alias the other columns like rnk?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` counts the amount of rows in a rowset. But what `COUNT(t.*)` must to count? If you want to count the amount of output rows which have according row part taken from `t` then you must count not total row part with `*` but some definite column or expresssion (either PK expression or an expression used in ON clause).

Comment: so in above use case use count(*) not with alias corect?